# want to store promise value in an array

Tags: protractor

I want to get all the values from a registration page and store all values in an array. How can I do that in protractor?

```js
var arr = new Array();  //declare array 
InputName.getAttribute("value")
         .then(function(value){
            arr[0]=value;  // want to store promise value in an array
         });
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code, it will first log `arr[0]` and then resolve Promise. Therefore, you may access that array's values in the next Promise. Something like this

```
var arr = new Array();  // <- this is by the way bad practice, use 'let arr = [];'
InputName.getAttribute("value")
         .then(function(value) {
            arr[0]=value;  // I would use arr.push(value)
         });
anotherInput.getAttribute("value")
         .then(function(value) {
            console.log(arr[0]); // your value should be accessible here
            arr.push(value) // push another value
         });
```

But, honestly, I've been working with Protractor fo a while now and I still have difficulties understanding promises... This why I'm using `async/await` in my tests so if I were to implement something like that I would end up having the following

```
let arr = [];
let value1 = await InputName.getAttribute("value");
arr.push(value1);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Clear, neat code with no hustle. Plus protractor team is actually removing promise_manager, so one day when you update it your code will not work anymore. Then why not switch earlier

Comment: Thanks man.for your efforts I will implement the same in my code. I also got the solution of that.